# Springfox API docu with xml response- Workaround for @XmlAttribute

Tags: jackson, jaxb, swagger-ui, springfox

I have some issues setting up Springfox for usage in Swagger UI.
I got it working in general, but the XML examples which are created are partly wrong because some xml annoations are not considered by springfox.

I have these models:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ApplicatorUnits")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
public class EHDTOApplicatorUnits
{
    @XmlElement(name = "UnitGroup")
    private List<EHDTOUnitGroup> ehdtoUnitGroups;

    public List<EHDTOUnitGroup> getEhdtoUnitGroups()
    {
        return ehdtoUnitGroups;
    }

    public void setEhdtoUnitGroups(List<EHDTOUnitGroup> ehdtoUnitGroups)
    {
        this.ehdtoUnitGroups = ehdtoUnitGroups;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "UnitGroup")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
public class EHDTOUnitGroup
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "unit")
    private List<EHDTOUnit> ehdtoUnits;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<EHDTOUnit> getEhdtoUnits()
    {
        return ehdtoUnits;
    }

    public void setEhdtoUnits(List<EHDTOUnit> ehdtoUnits)
    {
        this.ehdtoUnits = ehdtoUnits;
    }
}
```

You see some usages of @XmlAttribute, @XmlRootElement and @XmlElement.
After adding jackson jaxb annotation introspectors (I tried different ways) the XML was partly correct, as the @XmlAttribute annotations have been considered after this step:

```
JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
jaxbAnnotationModule.setPriority(Priority.PRIMARY);
mapper.registerModule(jaxbAnnotationModule);
/*AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new XmlJaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory()); //new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory());
AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospectorPair(primary,secondary);
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);*/
```

However, the other 2 are still ignored, resulting in this example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EHDTOApplicatorUnits>
  <UnitGroup>
    <name>string</name>
    <unit>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>string</name>
      <unitSystem>string</unitSystem>
    </unit>
  </UnitGroup>
</EHDTOApplicatorUnits>
```

While the real output of the API is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ApplicatorUnits>
  <UnitGroup name="coefTempErrorSpan">
    <unit>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>% span /10K</name>
      <unitSystem>SI</unitSystem>
    </unit>
    <unit>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>% span /50F</name>
      <unitSystem>SI</unitSystem>
    </unit>
  </UnitGroup>
...
</ApplicatorUnits>
```

You see the different naming of the root element, and also the "name" of the UnitGroup which is not an attribute in the example xml but an own child-node.

I found I can use @ApiModel(value = "ApplicatorUnits") as workaround for @XmlRootElement but what about @XmlAttribute, is there also a workaround? @ApiModelProperty does not seem to work for this case. Does somebody have an idea how to workaround this issue?

Comment: As it seems nobody has an idea yet, I would also be interested in alternative solutions as replacement of springfox....

Comment: Did you find a solution?